# Getting info about Kafka connect cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm currently having Kafka connect cluster with two nodes, using the same `group.id`

when using curl /connectors I can get list of my connectors created, but I can't see infos about alive nodes, Health check ...

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect doesn't expose such information from the REST API.

The best you could do is hit `/connectors/{name}/status`, then build up a set of all the running workers, but that still isn't 100% guaranteed to give you all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late, but one way to improve your KC cluster monitoring would be to use this Kafka REST extension:
https://github.com/LoObp4ck/kafka-connect-healthchecks

And then have your monitoring periodic job to check for this endpoint to ensure all connectors tasks are running fine.
We use it in production and it does the job

The jar is also available in maven central as follows :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.loobpack.kafka-connect-healthchecks</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-connect-healthcheck-extension</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```